# How to Display search records from database

Tags: html, jsp

i want to search record from database in jsp  using id.
if id exists in database then display edit.jsp otherwise display any error message like record not found in db.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Selecting data from DB using MYSQL:

```
<%
    Connection conn = null; 
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null; 

    try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<DATABASE_NAME>?user=<USER NAME>&password=<PASSWORD>");

          if(!conn.isClosed())
          out.println("MySql Connection Success..");

          ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *, count(*) as totalRecords FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = 1");
          rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();

          while (rs1.next()) {
             if(rs1.getInt("totalRecords") > 0) {
                 out.println("Record Found");
             } else {
                 out.println("Record Not Found");
             }
          }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("Error:"+e);
    } finally {
         if (rs1!= null) rs1.close(); 
         if (ps1!= null) ps1.close();
         if (conn!= null) conn.close();
    }

%>
```

Comment: sorry..its a typo... if (rs1!= null) rs1.close();

Comment: totalRecords is  database field?

Comment: totalRecords is alias name for count(*) value

Comment: have u applied correct db config details?? what s the error u r getting??

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better if you use a servlet too . else you can go with the JSP itself , but you need to use scriplets , which is considered as a bad practice refer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

In your servlet, do something like this ,

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
```

1. get the parameters using

   `request.getParameter`
2. Connect to DB, Select id from table , iterate and if  **Id** exists return a boolean variable with value true else return it as false
3. Check the value of the boolean variable if true , redirect it to **edit.jsp** else display an error msg

**Note:** For redirecting either use `sendRedirect` or `RequestDispatcher` . Refer this links could be more useful

[Creating simple JSP app](http://www.javatpoint.com/login-form-in-jsp)

[Start from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/geysj.html)

Hope it Helps !!